# Rails4 Date Time Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to validate Date and Time in Rails 4.

Tries to use a couple of Gems but they dont seem to work with Rails 4. 
Any recommendations?

Gems i tried

1. https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/
2. https://github.com/codegram/date_validator
3. https://github.com/nickstenning/validates_date_time

I am trying to Validate

1. Birthday
2. Start/End DateTime of an Event

Comment: better add custom validations

Comment: What validations are you planning? You can validate perfectly using simple ruby code. If you put in some feedback, some answer might appear.

Comment: 1. Birthday 2. Start/End Date and Time for an Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and follow all the flow.

**Source:**https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/validates_date_time

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a Rails 4-compatible fork of the original validates_timeliness gem by Adam Meehan

```
gem 'jc-validates_timeliness', '~> 3.1.1'
# source: https://github.com/johncarney/validates_timeliness
```